# Ruby on Rails Model Association with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is my model

```
class Location
  has_many :areas
end

class Area
  belongs_to :location
end
```

The Controller

```
def create
   @area = Area.new(area_params)
   @area.location_id = session[:current_location]
end
```

How can I associate this model when I'll create a new area?
something like this?

```
def create
 @area = @location.areas.create(area_params)
end
```

Comment: You could do that. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, but I recived the error message undefined areas method. I forgot to talk but I wanna set the location_id, So Need I add two params like this: `@area = @location.areas.create(area_params, location_id = session[:current_location] )`?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to set the location_id attribute upon creation. It should be included in the params. If you provide the full controller file I could be more specific.

Yes, include the `area_params` can include a `location_id` and it should be a column in the database.

Comment: Well, You mean add an area_id column on the database? The function was defined like this: `def area_params
        params.require(:area).permit(:description,
                                     :name)
    end`